# NavigationStack inside TabView inside NavigationStack throws

Tags: ios, swift, swiftui, swiftui-tabview, swiftui-navigationstack

I'm trying to migrate a coordinator pattern using `UINavigationController` into the new `NavigationStack`.

The navigation flow is quite complex, but I've made a simple project to simplify it to this:

```
NavigationStack
  -> MainScreen
    -> TabView
      -> FirstTab
        -> NavigationStack
          -> FirstTabFirst
          -> FirstTabSecond
      -> SecondTab
        -> SecondTabScreen
  -> Second Top Screen
```

Althoug the first Screens in each `NavigatorStack` are actually the root view of the navigator, it shouldn't be a problem as I can't even get it to navigate to something.

All the navigators have their state defined by a `@StateObject` to allow for both programatic imperative navigation and `NavigationLink`, similar to what a Coordinator pattern provides.

Upon launching the app, it immediatelly throws in the `@main` line, with no further information about the call stack:

```
Thread 1: Fatal error: 'try!' expression unexpectedly raised an error: SwiftUI.AnyNavigationPath.Error.comparisonTypeMismatch
```

This is the code for the whole app:

```swift
import SwiftUI

protocol NavigationRoute: Hashable {
    associatedtype V: View
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func view() -> V
}

enum Top: NavigationRoute {
    case first, second
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func view() -> some View {
        switch self {
        case .first: TopFirst()
        case .second: TopSecond()
        }
    }
}

enum Tab: NavigationRoute {
    case first, second
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func view() -> some View {
        switch self {
        case .first: TabFirst()
        case .second: TabSecond()
        }
    }
    
    var label: String {
        switch self {
        case .first: return "First"
        case .second: return "Second"
        }
    }
    
    var systemImage: String {
        switch self {
        case .first: return "house"
        case .second: return "person.fill"
        }
    }
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func tab() -> some View {
        view()
            .tabItem { Label(label, systemImage: systemImage) }
            .tag(self)
    }
}

enum FirstTab: NavigationRoute {
    case first, second
    
    @ViewBuilder
    func view() -> some View {
        switch self {
        case .first: FirstTabFirst()
        case .second: FirstTabSecond()
        }
    }
}

class StackNavigator<Route: NavigationRoute>: ObservableObject {
    @Published var routes: [Route] = []
}

class TabNavigator<Route: NavigationRoute>: ObservableObject {
    @Published public var tab: Route
    
    public init(initial: Route) {
        tab = initial
    }
    
    public func navigate(_ route: Route) {
        tab = route
    }
}

@main
struct NavigationStackTestApp: App {
    @StateObject var navigator = StackNavigator<Top>()

    var body: some Scene {
        WindowGroup {
            NavigationStack(path: $navigator.routes) {
                TopFirst().navigationDestination(for: Top.self) {
                    $0.view()
                }
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TopFirst: View {
    @StateObject var navigator = TabNavigator<Tab>(initial: .first)

    var body: some View {
        TabView(selection: $navigator.tab) {
            Tab.first.tab()
            Tab.second.tab()
        }
    }
}

struct TopSecond: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Top Second")
    }
}

struct TabFirst: View {
    @StateObject var navigator = StackNavigator<FirstTab>()
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationStack(path: $navigator.routes) {
            FirstTabFirst().navigationDestination(for: FirstTab.self) {
                $0.view()
            }
        }
    }
}

struct TabSecond: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("Tab Second")
    }
}

struct FirstTabFirst: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("First Tab First")
    }
}

struct FirstTabSecond: View {
    var body: some View {
        Text("First Tab Second")
    }
}
```

To avoid it from crashing I have to replace the `NavigationStack` of the first tab with an `EmptyView()`, that is changing:

```
case .first: TabFirst()
```

to

```
case .first: EmptyView()
```

But of course after doing that the first tab is missing and the app doesn't do what it's supposed to.

Has anyone encountered something like this or has an idea of how to get this working? SwiftUI is closed source and it's documentation is very limited so it's really hard to know what's really going on under the hood.

EDIT:

Using `NavigationPath` as state for `StackNavigator` doesn't crash the app, but any navigation in the first tab's `NavigationStack` pushes a new view in the top navigator and hides the bottom tab bar.

I'm assuming you just can't have two navigation stacks in the same hierarchy and expect it to work as you would assume.

Comment: I am not sure but I played with your code and the problem seems to be the navigationpath. The navigationpath of your two navigators are initiated with Top and FirstTab respectively. This difference seems to be the reason. If you initiate navigationstack without using Path, or with the same path (say both using Top), then this won't be a problem.

Comment: I assume the paths are colliding and the issue is the top navigator throws an error because it cannot compare it's declared type to the lower navigator, but the lower navigator should not bubble up into the top navigator, it should be handled and the bubbling stopped. That's why using top in both could fix it, but it's not what the app is supposed to do

Answer (score 4):

Using two `NavigationStack`s in the same hierarchy doesn't work very well as their internal states collide, I would not recommend it and it seems to cause the error. The error is thrown when the lower navigator is declared because it's declared type is also handled by the top navigator, which doesn't have a handler declared for the lower navigator's tap in its `navigationDestination`.

It is better to use conditional rendering and manual animation/transitions in the upper level and then from there render only one `NavigationStack` per hierarchy. There is no issue using `NavigationStack` inside `TabView` as long as that `TabView` is not itself inside a `NavigationStack`.

`NavigationPath` can be used to support multiple unrelated types in the state stack.

Comment: This is jan 2024,  Still we can't nest navigation stacks?